# Problems changing div text with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have this method that updates some buttons when the page size is small enough that it detects it as mobile. Because I notice that some fonts where bigger than others inside the buttons I want to change the text using javascript/jQuery, but nothing I do seems to be working.

The code in the page I'm trying to change looks like this:

```
<div id="btn-take-me-to-help" class="btn-long-green">
  <div class="btn-center-container-long-green">
    <div class="btn-text-blue">
      <span>Take me to the help center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I'm trying to change it with jQuery:

```
$("#btn-take-me-to-help span").text("I changed the text!!!");
```

I have also tried using .html() and tested with the css as well and haven't had any luck.

<-- Added General Info -->

I have jQuery loaded correctly, since i'm using it for everything else in my script and they are working. The console in chrome doesn't give me any errors either.

I tried the same statement in the css file as well #btn-take-me-to-help span{...} and just trying changing the size of the font, and it didn't even do that, which has me wondering there has to be something else happening here, but no clue of what

<-- -->

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you are selecting wrong div . select span and then change html content of span tag.

Comment: Seems to work here - http://jsfiddle.net/n8yee8qc/1/

Comment: I think he is missing $(document).ready .. Else why wouldn't it work?.. Maybe obsolete version?

Comment: Wow it does work there, now I'm even more confuse of why isn't this working! :s

Comment: It works fine on fiddle - leading me to believe that he has not got his script loaded correctly, his jQuery may be loaded incorrectly or he may have a deprecated version of jQuery 

can you check these options?

Comment: Even in jQuery 1.4 it is working.. I'm suspecting that he is not including jQuery (or not correctly).. What does `if (jQuery) alert("jQuery");` do? (@kalaxt)

Comment: Did you use jQuery Library ? **`:)`**

Comment: just go to the browser console (chrome) or firebug console and type $("#btn-take-me-to-help span") and see if you get any results or errors. Then you will know the problem.

Comment: Or, right click inspect element and then head to the console tab, any errors will be displayed here.

Comment: I bet that he is actually testing LOCALLY and included jQuery by not parsing the http protocol in the src :P (and including the CDN)

Comment: Or he has script loaded elsewhere on execution that is causing JS execution to halt.

Comment: I have jQuery loaded correctly, since i'm using it for everything else in my script and they are working. The console in chrome doesn't give me any errors either. 

I tried the same statement in the css file as well #btn-take-me-to-help span{...} and just trying changing the size of the font, and it didn't even do that, which has me wondering there has to be something else happening here, but no clue of what.

Comment: You don't have a link to the page we can see do you?

Comment: @j08691 no, unfortunately is a private site I'm working on so I can't provide a link to it.

Comment: Well there's definitely a disconnect somewhere. The fiddle shows the code works, but you said you get no errors. Can you update the example code to be more representative of what you're working with?

Comment: @j08691 mmmm.. what else would you like to see that may help? part of the css? maybe there is something that over-rights the javascript?

Comment: can you try adding an id directly on your span and try selecting that?

Comment: also do you have multiple #btn-take-me-to-help on your page by any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. Thank all of you, you were all right. The code actually does work with no problems, it was all because of of me testing the code in a different view that I shouldn't for hours....

Thanks again and sorry for taking your time. What a great community!

Answer (score -1):

maybe you haven't load the jquery librarie :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn-take-me-to-help span").text("I changed the text!!!");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$("#btn-take-me-to-help span").text("I changed the text!!!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btn-take-me-to-help" class="btn-long-green">
  <div class="btn-center-container-long-green">
    <div class="btn-text-blue">
      <span>Take me to the help center</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: All you did was add the <script> reference? Was this his issue? I'd appreciate if he comments letting us know.

Comment: Could be a comment at best!

Answer (score -3):

Try...

```
$("#btn-take-me-to-help>div>div>span").text("I changed the text!!!");
```

Comment: Why would your selector be any better?

Comment: The problem seems rather odd, so why not try the unexpected?

Comment: You shouldn't post it as an answer unless you have tried and tested yourself @Estrobyn, this is a guess at best.

Comment: Well yes, it works, but its the same code the OP has essentially. You both started and ended at the same points; you just took a different path.

Comment: We've derived that the issue isn't the literal code - rather the means or lack of jQuery library.

Comment: See is your answer helpful for future visitors ? No becasue you just included library and thats it.

Comment: Ok, this was my first answer on stackoverflow: Just wanted to give back something to the community, because they helped me out in such a gracious manner... Lesson learned, sorry guys!